# HTMLEditor focus cursor inside textarea

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I've a simple panel with an HTML Editor inside it.

I only want to focus my cursor inside the textarea of the component.
I've tried to focus it on afterrender, to set the component default focused, but I can't make it work.

this my code, what should i do? are there possibilities to set this textarea on focus?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyViewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.myviewport',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.MyViewportViewModel',
        'Ext.panel.Panel',
        'Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor'
    ],

    viewModel: {
        type: 'myviewport'
    },
    layout: 'fit',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'My Panel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'htmleditor',
                    height: 150,
                    id: 'myEditor',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

});
```

Also tryed with this

```
{
   xtype: 'htmleditor',
   height: 150,
   id: 'myEditor',
   fieldLabel: 'Label',
   listeners: {
       afterrender: 'onMyEditorAfterRender'
   }
}



Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyViewportViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.myviewport',

    onMyEditorAfterRender: function(component, eOpts) {
        component.focus();
    }

});
```

The problem seems to be on the browser i'm using, the second code works on firefox but not on chrome and edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Afterrender` event can make it

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyViewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.myviewport',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.MyViewportViewModel',
        'Ext.panel.Panel',
        'Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor'
    ],

    viewModel: {
        type: 'myviewport'
    },
    layout: 'fit',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'My Panel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'htmleditor',
                    height: 150,
                    id: 'myEditor',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label',
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: {
                            fn: function(component) {
                                component.focus();
                            }
                        }
                }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

});
```

Comment: it can't work, component is all the component including his toolbar and the input textarea.

Comment: listener is on htmleditor,  so in afterrender event component will be htmleditor.

Comment: I have tested it before writing here. it's working. if you want to make it on panel's afterrender event, replace logic in afterrender's functino with component.down("htmleditor").focus()

Comment: what version of extjs are you using? I've added code with your try but for me it doesn't work

Comment: it must work in any version. hold on 1 minute. I will try it for extjs 5 too

Comment: Ok, maybe it dipends on browser? Adding onfocus event to htmleditor it fires but i can't directly write on his textarea

Comment: I think is because the htmleditor component has got 2 items inside it (toolbar and input). I also tryed this: component.items.items[1].focus(); but nothing changes

Comment: ok tested now using firefox, and here your code works, but on chrome and edge no way to do this

Comment: ext5 had plenty of bugs, I have spiked this version and never used it.  maybe this one is one of bugs.

Comment: perfect xD i'm using 5.1.2